# Could not build wheels for PyAudio which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I am trying to create DAGs on Apache airflow which is installed on Docker. I am trying to install some python packages using a requirements file and I get the below error message. I have mentioned my requirements and Dockerfile contents as well.

Upgrading pip was the most popular suggestion for this problem, I used this command in my dockerfile: ***RUN pip install --upgrade pip*** , but that gave an error.

Please let me know how to fix the error and upgrade pip in docker.

Error Message

```
12.18   Building wheel for PyAudio (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
12.18   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
12.18    command: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmprtkzoywg
12.18        cwd: /tmp/pip-install-qebze68r/pyaudio
12.18   Complete output (14 lines):
12.18   running bdist_wheel
12.18   running build
12.18   running build_py
12.18   creating build
12.18   creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
12.18   creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyaudio
12.18   copying src/pyaudio/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyaudio
12.18   running build_ext
12.18   building 'pyaudio._portaudio' extension
12.18   creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
12.18   creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
12.18   creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/pyaudio
12.18   gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c src/pyaudio/main.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/pyaudio/main.o
12.18   error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
12.18   ----------------------------------------
12.18   ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio
12.19   Building wheel for wave (setup.py): started
12.66   Building wheel for wave (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
12.66   Created wheel for wave: filename=Wave-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl size=1239 sha256=12e9279e72c564e841b0bcdf183b803b27b39ec157071ea3a8241c306227fc0a
12.66   Stored in directory: /home/airflow/.cache/pip/wheels/83/63/90/6a2d80dee3920a33ad8aa701add00f54423ddda1dd4005f847
12.66 Successfully built wave
12.66 Failed to build PyAudio
12.66 ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyAudio which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
12.73 WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
12.73 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -o pipefail -e -u -x -c pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.0.2
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

requirements.txt

```
PyAudio
wave
numpy
matplotlib
pandas
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update `pip` as well as install `portaudio19-dev` as suggested in [this issue](https://github.com/ardha27/AI-Waifu-Vtuber/issues/49).

So, your Dockerfile should look like this one:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.0.2
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential portaudio19-dev
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```